# which one is best in using jquery library?

Tags: jquery, shared-libraries

I'm little confused, with calling jquery library from google or download and keep in our server itself.
which one is good? and why?

Can anyone clear me?

thanks in advance.

Comment: based upon the two conflicting but correct answers I would say that this is very much an opinion based question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both have their advantages and disadvantages:

**Using Google**

- +1 You don't have to download anything
- +1 Chances are that it will get to the browser faster than your own server (may even exist in browser's cache)
- -1 Google may be offline (*no, it won't*)
- -1 You don't know if the contents will change or stay there forever

**Using your own server**

- +1 You control the script version, and know that it will be there as long as your site stays there
- +1 You don't depend on anything (if for example a crazy DNS blocks Google)
- -1 It's probably slower and not cached the first time your site loads
- -1 You can't update the version by changing a few characters in your code

Answer (score 1):

Call the jquery library from google.

1. Decreased latency,
2. Increased parallelism
3. Better caching.

Comment: Ya but what happens if google is down?

Comment: I doubt google would be offline long enough (if at all) for it to be noticeable in your site..

Comment: If google is down, chances are that your site will be, too. Common cases that this may happen: meteor crash, worldwide electricity failure, etc

Answer (score 1):

If you download it yourself and serve it from your servers, you can make sure that it is always available and can control the version of the file.

For some business, the internal website may not even have an external internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

Calling it from google will likely decrease you page load time. The only down side is that if for what ever reason google doesnt serve your request then the user requesting the page is going to be missing that library.

However for the gained performance and the extremely small change google fails to serve the file I would recommend pulling from google.

Answer (score 1):

Including common libraries from Google or other cloud sources is normally **faster** for the end user. Because there is a huge chance that the user already has the library in their browser cache ( from other sites that he has visited with the same library ).

Including your files from different servers also increase your **site overall performance**.

In addition, they also let you **define the library version**.

So all in all, I think using content delivery networks like Google is a better choice.